# Load multiple txt files to a single data frame and retain name as a column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and I'm trying to load 100 or so txt files with three columns Name, Frequency and Gender into a single data frame. The files are all name "yob1990.txt" etc.

I can get all the files into R but I've no idea how to add a column with just the year in it.. can anyone help please?

Comment: So do you have them in a single `data.frame`? Or are they in the global environment with names `yob1990.txt`, etc.

Comment: Code! We must have code!

Answer (score 1):

I would use a workflow something like this, which assumes (1) that the only `.txt` files in the specified path are the ones you want read in, and (2) that the only numerals in the filenames are the digits of the years.

```
f <- list.files('path/to/files', patt='\\.txt$', full.names=TRUE) 
# replace path above as required
d <- do.call(rbind, lapply(f, function(x) {
  d <- read.table(x, header=TRUE) # add sep argument as required
  d$Year <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', basename(x)))
  d
}))
```

`f` will be a vector of full paths to the files you need to read in.

`lapply` considers each filename in turn (each element of `f`), temporarily refers to that filename as `x`, and performs everything in between the curly braces.

`gsub('\\D', '', basename(x))` performs a "find and replace"-type operation on `basename(x)` (which is the filename of the currently considered file, excluding the structure of the directory containing the file). We look for all non-digit characters (`'\\D'`), and replace them with nothing (`''`). We add the result of this `gsub` operation (which is the year, assuming no other digits lurk in the filename) to a new `Year` column of the data.frame.

Finally, we return `d`, and once `lapply` has performed this procedure on all files in `f`, we row bind them all together with `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `fread` and `rbindlist` from `data.table`.  If the files are in the working directory,

```
  f1 <- list.files(pattern="^yob.*\\.txt")
  f1  #created 3 files
  #[1] "yob1990.txt" "yob1991.txt" "yob1992.txt"

  library(data.table)
  library(stringr)
  year <- as.numeric(str_extract(f1, perl("[0-9]+(?=\\.txt)")))
  res <- rbindlist(Map(`cbind`, lapply(f1, fread), year=year))

  head(res)
 #    Name Frequency Gender year
 #1:   Sam        24   Male 1990
 #2:  Gobi        22   Male 1990
 #3:  Rose        44 Female 1990
 #4: Anita        35 Female 1990
 #5:  John        44   Male 1991
 #6: Sofia        52 Female 1991
```

Or you could use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
  devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
  library(tidyr)
  res1 <- unnest(setNames(lapply(f1, fread), year), year)
  head(res1)
  #  year  Name Frequency Gender
  #1 1990   Sam        24   Male
  #2 1990  Gobi        22   Male
  #3 1990  Rose        44 Female
  #4 1990 Anita        35 Female
  #5 1991  John        44   Male
  #6 1991 Sofia        52 Female
```